# GNAT Studio ADA getting error "expected type "Standard.Integer"

Tags: arrays, types, ada, gnat

In this [Intro to Ada Course section about Arrays](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/arrays.html) it shows that I can use a user defined type "Index" to index an array but when I try to index an array using a user defined type it says expected type "Standard.Integer". The reason why I'm asking this is because it explicitly states that you can use any discrete type to index an array.

```
procedure Cipher is
   type Byte is mod 2**8;
   type BufferArray is array ( 0 .. 15 ) of Byte;
   type Index is range 1 .. 16;
   Buffer: BufferArray := (0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
   buber: Byte := 255;
begin
   --  Insert code here.
   for I in Index loop
      Put( Byte'Image(Buffer(I)) ); --error shows up here
   end loop;
   null;
end Cipher;
```

Is it just possible that its an issue with this specific version of GNAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the array as being indexed with your own defined type:

```
type BufferArray is array (Index) of Byte;
```

As a bonus, this definition removes automatically one bug in your code.

Comment: Index type, 1 .. 16, and array index type, 0 .. 15, are different types. By the way, this is one of strengths of Ada.